# Angular ui-grid: how to refresh 2nd grid based on row selected value of 1st grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

There are 2 grids grid1 grid2.
My requirement is: When I select a row in grid1, grid2 should get refreshed. I am able to fetch the modified data based on the row selection from my service, but I am not able to get it to display on my grid2.
I tried

```
$scope.grid2 = function () { $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh();}
```

Both the above are in the RowSelectionChanged event inside the grid1 onRegisterAPI

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
            $scope.value = row.entity.MVE_VEID;
            console.log($scope.value);
            $scope.contractvalues = contracts.query({ id: $scope.value });
            console.log($scope.contractvalues);
            $scope.gridoptions2 = function () { $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);  $scope.gridApi.core.refresh(); }
            $scope.refresh = true;

        });
```

How can I refresh the data in grid2?

Current Code:
contrcontroller.js

```
<pre>

    angular
        .module('VendorApp')
        .controller('ang_contcontroller', ang_contcontroller);

    ang_contcontroller.$inject = ['$scope','contracts'];

    function ang_contcontroller($scope, contracts) {

        $scope.contractvalues = contracts.query({ id: $scope.value });
        $scope.gridoptions2 = {
            enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
            multiSelect: false,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableSelectAll: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            enablePagination: true,
            enablePaginationControls: true,
            paginationCurrentPage: 1,
            paginationPageSize: 100,
            maxVisibleColumnCount: 200,
            columnDefs: [
              { name: 'CONTRACTID', field: 'MCO_COID' },
              { name: 'NAME', field: 'CO_DESC' },
              { name: 'VENDORID', field: 'MCO_VEID' }
            ],
            data: $scope.contractvalues

        };
        $scope.gridoptions2.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi2 = gridApi;
        }

    }


vencontroller.js

    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
                $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                        $scope.value = row.entity.MVE_VEID;
                        console.log($scope.value);
                        $scope.contractvalues = contracts.query({ id: $scope.value });
                        console.log($scope.contractvalues);
                        $scope.gridoptions2 = {};
                        $scope.gridoptions2.data = $scope.contractvalues;
                        //$scope.gridApi2.refresh();
                        $scope.grid2 = function () {
                            $scope.gridApi2.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
                            $scope.gridApi2.core.refresh();
                        };
                        //$scope.grid2 = function () {
                        //     $scope.gridoptions2 = angular.copy($scope.gridoptions2);
                        //     $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL= function () { $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL); },$scope.gridApi.core.refresh(); );
                        // }
                        //$scope.refresh();
                        //$scope.gridoptions2 = function () { $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL); }
                    });

                });
    <code>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to update data for grid2
you wrote that you able to get modified base data say "newData".
Assign this new data to "$scope.gridoptions2.data"

$scope.gridoptions2.data = newData;

Comment: try to refresh your columndef with data , it will work

Comment: How to do that? refresh columndef with data? I am updating my question with my current code

Comment: Thanks, this is working now, my problem was that the 2 grids were under 2 different controllers and hence not working, once I moved both under one controller, the scope was the same and hence it started working.